# Entity SQL concatenation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-sql

I have a select in Entity SQL that returns simple strings, and I should concatenate to a string.

```
select (p.X + p.Y) from ExampleEntities.ExampleTable as p
group by p.X, p.Y
```

For example it returns 3 string and I should concatenate it to 1 string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to concatenate all rows or per row, but this is a per row solution:

```
from p in ExampleEntities.ExampleTable
select string.Concat(p.X, p.Y, p.Z)
```

If you want a single result you'll need the following:

```
var temp = (from p in ExampleEntities.ExampleTable
            select string.Concat(p.X, p.Y, p.Z)).ToList();

string result = temp.Aggregate((current, next) => current + next);
```

Comment: So i want to concatenate all the "example select" rows to 1 string.

Comment: Yes its a good idea, but you use linq, and i should do this in entity sql.